# Get-Acl list only Users

Tags: powershell

I need a list of all directories (recursive) which have user-permissions registered (not user-groups).

Something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\scripte | Get-Acl |
  Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'}
```

I think there must be some `Get-ADUser` stuff?

Comment: Are you looking for just AD users or local users as well? What about builtin security principals?

Comment: Hello, lust looking for AD users.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do, assuming that you have PowerShell v3 or newer:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\scripte -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {
  (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Access.IdentityReference -match "^$env:USERDOMAIN\\" -replace '^.*\\' |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq $_" }
}
```

If you're stuck with PowerShell v2 the statement gets a little more elaborate:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\scripte -Recurse | Where-Object {
  $_.PSIsContainer -and 
  (Get-Acl $_.FullName | Select-Object -Expand Access |
    Select-Object -Expand IdentityReference) -match "^$env:USERDOMAIN\\" -replace '^.*\\' |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq $_" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here ya go

```
{
param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$Path
)
$IDs = (get-acl $Path).Access | Select IdentityReference,FileSystemRights
foreach ($ID in $IDs)
{
    $thisUser = ($ID.IdentityReference).ToString()
    $Rights = ($ID.FileSystemRights).ToString()
    $User = $thisUser.split("\")[1]
    $Object = Get-ADobject -LDAPFilter "(samAccountName=$user)" | Select ObjectClass
    [pscustomObject]@{
        Type = $Object.ObjectClass
        samAccountName = $User
        Rights = $Rights
    }
}
```

}